# Segue a UItableView to another UITableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, model-view-controller, segue

I am unsure about what exactly you must keep separate when you have a multiple MVC project. Say I have two table view controllers, the first one displays a table and when i click on a cell it segues to the second table view controller. The information for the tables is created using methods in a third separate file called FlickrFetcher. The first table View has an instance created of FlickrFetcher allowing it to call the methods. Would I be allowed to import FlickrFetcher into the second table View controller too or am I supposed to keep these controllers separate and only pass the needed information via segue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of what is allowed by the language, you can certainly have an instance of the FlickrFetcher class in your second table view controller, or when you segue you could pass the reference to the same instance of the class from your first view controller to your second. Otherwise, what would perhaps be better would be to pass only the specific information you need for the second view controller from FlickrFetcher via segue (this depends on how much you need in your second view controller). It's mostly up to you, but passing via segue might be more efficient, and make more sense semantically. Hope this answers your question

Comment: I thought you are supposed to keep controllers separate though, would creating an instance by importing go against the MVC design pattern?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would be better to just pass the specific info you need for your second view controller via segue, if you want to follow MVC strictly. Just FYI though, if you copied the reference to the FlickrFetcher object in the segue (say if the second view controller had a flickrFetcher property), you wouldn't be creating a new instance, as long as the second view controller's flickrFetcher property was a strong pointer.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean a protocol on the FlickrFetcher class so that your second view controller has a pointer to an id that conforms to that protocol, in which case I guess that would work, that way you only make the necessary stuff available to the second view controller.

Comment: How about making the protocol in the first TableView Controller which has an instance of flickrFetcher? or would it be better to do it right in the FlickrFetcher Class?

Comment: IMHO the protocol should be in the same file as the FlickrFetcher class (probably the interface file)